# rails create action in multiple forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, rendering

I have a create action in the controller that I use for a form on the user page as well as in the user index. I want to redirect to the same page the user is on when submitting the form after the form is submitted. This is what I have right now and the form only redirects to @user or '/users'. How can I get it so the user goes back to the page they submitted the form from?

```
def create
 @user = User.find(params[:relationship][:followed_id])
 current_user.follow!(@user)
 redirect_to @user or '/users'
end
```

Comment: If you have new method, you can try `redirect_to new`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

> redirect_to :back

This will redirect the user back to the page that they submitted the form.